# Using LPtoDP API problem (GDI API)

Tags: winapi, hook, gdi

I am hooking the ExtTextOut GDI API.
There I want to retrieve the exact location of the output String.

```
BOOL ExtTextOut( 
  __in  HDC hdc, 
  __in  int X, 
  __in  int Y, 
  __in  UINT fuOptions, 
  __in  const RECT *lprc, 
  __in  LPCTSTR lpString, 
  __in  UINT cbCount, 
  __in  const INT *lpDx 
);
```

In a specific case I am getting ETO_CLIPPED for the fuOptions param which mean I can get the location of the string from the RECT param or from the X,Y params.
However when I use the LPtoDP API for translating the location (RECT or X,Y) I get wrong location (before translating I get negative values).

I guess it has a wrong offset, however when I check the followings I see no indicaton for that:

> Map Mode is MM_TEXT (default)
>   GetWindowOrgEx is 0,0
>   GetViewportOrgEx is 0,0
>   GetWindowExtEx is 1,1
>   GetViewportExtEx is 1,1

Does anyone have any idea, any help will be appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: You're *hooking* it?  Looks to me like you're using the wrong device context.

Comment: can you elaborate please ? how can I use a wrong DC within the ExtTextOutW call ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, specifying ETO_CLIPPED in the ExtTextOut fuOptions param 
does not imply that the text will be output to that clip, meaning that it is not guaranteed that the device context is of type display device context, and the device context that is used can be a memory device context, as in my case,  and therefore do not contains the right coordinates.

> msdn: ETO_CLIPPED The text will be clipped to the rectangle.